# sed append text from file onto line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have some bash that calculates 90% of the total system memory in KB and outputs this into a file:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{SUM += $1} END { printf "%d", SUM/100*90}' | awk '{print $1}' > mem.txt
```

I then want to copy the value into another file (/tmp/limits.conf) and append to a single line.

The below searches for the string "soft memlock" and writes the output of `mem.txt` created earlier into the /tmp/limistest.conf

```
sed -i '/soft\smemlock/r mem.txt' /tmp/limitstest.conf
```

However the script outputs as below:

```
oracle   soft memlock
1695949
```

I want it to output like this:

```
oracle   soft memlock 1695949
```

I have tried quite a few things but can't get this to output correctly.

Thanks

*Edit* here is some of the text in input file /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:          18884388 kB
MemFree:            1601952 kB
MemAvailable:       1607620 kB
```

Comment: Consider [edit]ing to add a [mcve].

Comment: wrt your edit to show input file contents - if "MemTotal" only appears once in the file, why are you sum-ing it and printing at the END instead of just printing it where it occurs? If it occurs multiple times then show that in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a guess since you didn't provide sample input/output but all you need is something like:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    if (/MemTotal/) {
        split($0,f,/:/)
        $0 = f[2]
        sum += $1
    }
    next
}
/soft[[:space:]]+memlock/ { $0 = $0 OFS int(sum/100*90) }
{ print }
' /proc/meminfo /tmp/limitstest.conf > tmp &&
mv tmp /tmp/limitstest.conf
```

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, Thanks. I need do some more reading to figure out how exactly this works :)

Comment: It can probably be simplified but idk what your input file looks like so all I could do was translate your existing script into awk.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @Ed Morton I have added a sample of the input file to the original question if you want to look at shortening it

Comment: Yes you did but you didn't respond to my comment I added under your question after you added that sample so I still don't know what you're really working with wrt input.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is overly complicated: there is no need to store the output in a file and then append it into another file.

What if you just store the value in a variable and then add it into your file?

```
var=$(command)
sed "/soft memlock/s/.*/& $var/" /tmp/limitstest.conf
```

Once you are confident with the output, add the `-i` in the sed operation.

Where, in fact, `command` can be something `awk` alone handles:

```
awk '/MemTotal/ {sum+=$2} END { printf "%d", SUM/100*90}' /proc/meminfo
```

---

See a test on the `sed` part:

```
$ cat a
hello
oracle soft memlock
bye
$ var=2222
$ sed "/soft memlock/s/.*/& $var/" a
hello
oracle soft memlock 2222
bye
```

Comment: Hello yes I could rely on user input but that's not my ideal scenario. The awk does not seem to work and outputs 0, I think this is because awk is reading the full line input and not just the numeric values on that line (hence why I have used cut -d f2)

Comment: @senator404 my approach was using `awk -F:` so that it would get the 2nd field. I updated to use the normal field separator, since I assume your `/proc/meminfo` lines are the typical `parameter: NN units`.